# Visual C++ Form Opening

Tags: c++, vba, visual-studio

While I use the following code to open a different form in Visual Studio, How do I use the button to open up more than one copy of the same form. Right now the program only allows the user to use the form and cannot open another.

```
         AddProduct ^ form = gcnew AddProduct;
         form->ShowDialog();
```

Answer (score 0):

use Show() method insted
see [Control.Show Method](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.control.show(v=vs.110).aspx)